# Is it possible to change two or more Dataframe by their Concatenated version?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am working on the widely known [Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) on Kaggle to practice Data Analysis and Machine Learning tools.

The Dataset is split between a train_set and a test_set. Because I will change the structure of the Data to create new features I concatenated the two DataFrame as follows:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('../input/test.csv')
combined_data = pd.concat([train_data, test_data])
```

At some point, I want to create a new column based on the name title of the people so I did this:

```
combined_data["NameTitle"] = combined_data.Name.str.extract(r"(\w+\.)")
```

What I would like now is to get some visualization of the train_data of this new column, but the column doesn't exist for the `train_data` DataFrame:

```
train_data.columns
Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')
```

I know that [pandas.concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) returns a new DataFrame but I thought it might be using the DataFrame concatenated behind the scene.

Is it possible to change the structure of the DataFrames that were concatenated by changing the whole DataFrame or do I have to split again at the end of the modifications and to reassign my train and test sets?

Comment: A better idea would be to call `str.extract` on both train and test to create the column, and then call concat on them after that.

Comment: True, but I gave only one example of the modifications I want to do on both DataFrame. The idea is that I don't want to (re)assign every time I do a modification both sets, so I was hoping there would be another solution that would allow me to modify both the DataFrame in one code and be able to see the modifications on the split DataFrame. Here I might just sound lazy with only two DataFrame, but in a more general perspective, I think it would be particularly interesting if you have, let's say, 10 or 100 hundred DataFrame :).

Comment: The next obvious solution would be to create a function with of transformations called `def transform_df(x): ...` then do `pd.concat(map(transform_df, [train, test])), axis=1)` or something of the sort.

Comment: I think this is, along with Juan Estevez answer, the answer I was looking for, there is no way to do what I want with a concatenated DataFrame but it is simply possible by using list or functions like yours to change different DataFrames and then concat them. Or concat them and split them again after transformation. Thank you :).

Comment: I'd suggest using keys in a `pd.concat` so that you can easily reference them later.  `combined_data = pd.concat({'train': train_data, 'test': test_data})`  Then you can act on the entire combination at once **and** access the parts with an `combined_data.xs('train')` or `combined_data.loc['test']` cc: @cs95

Comment: Thanks, @piRSquared ! I guess this solution is even closer to what I want than the answer of Juan Estevez, I guess both solutions would work depending on what you want to do but yours is definitely better for DataFrames you absolutely want to concatenate and Juan's is the way to go for different DataFrame on which you want to perform the same tasks but not necessarily concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a speed issue?
If it's not, applying the same set of actions to many data frames at once isn't hard to do:

```
dfs = [train_data, test_data]

for df in dfs:
    df["NameTitle"] = df.Name.str.extract(r"(\w+\.)")
    # And any other such actions
```

Comment: It is not a speed issue, I just wanted to know if there was a nicer way to do that in one DataFrame that holds two or more other DataFrame by avoiding using lists and loops to do so. 
I don't think this exists because after some thoughts, this is not the way Pandas is intended to work, it always returns new DataFrames to force people explicitly changing the Data if they want to do that.
I will accept your answer because I think it is what someone else would be looking for and this would be the closest answer to my question. Thank you :).